# Two Foreign Key on same Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have Class something Like this:

```
public class RelatedRequest{

  public RelatedRequest(int Id){
     RelatedRequestId = Id;
  }

   public int RequestId {get; set;}

   public int RelatedRequestId {get; set;}

   public string comment {get; set;}
}
```

And Another class Like:

```
public class Request{

  public int Id{get; set;}  

  internal virtual ICollection<RelatedRequest> InternalRelatedRequests { get; } = new List<RelatedRequest>();

}
```

I have table for Request class as where **Id** is Primary key in Table.
And Table for Related Request columns are: **RequestID**(Foreign KEY same as **Id** from Request), **RelatedRequestId**(Foreign KEY same as **Id** from Request), Comment(string).

I am using Fluent API for EF Configuration:

```
  public class RequestConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Request> {
      public RequestConfiguration() {
         HasKey(r => r.Id);
         HasMany(r => r.InternalRelatedRequests).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(rr 
                                                                => rr.RequestId);

      }
}
```

While inserting Request Object in Db I need new Id from Request and Want to update RelatedRequest object's relatedRequestId with the new Id from Request.

I am doing something like this:

```
NewRequestEntity = new Request();
OldRequestEntity.InternalRelatedRequests.Add(new RelatedRequest(newRequest.Id));

DbContext.Set<Request>().Add(NewRequestEntity)
base.SaveChanges();
```

I am always getting RelatedRequestId(newRequest.Id) as Zero. So EF is throwing Dbupdate exception as per voilation of Foreign Key.
I am new to EF. cna anyone please Explains me whats going on here.

Comment: Shortly: Add **second** `ICollection<RelatedRequest>` to `Request` and associate it with `RelatedRequestId` of `RelatedRequest`.

Comment: Thanks, It Worked.